# Wordpress adding logout menu condition failed

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I successfully integrated Laravel with Wordpress and I want to add a logout feature once the `Auth::user()->id` is present. When I put `print_r(Auth::user()->id);` it appears to give me the right user `id` but my problem now is that when I tried to put a condition where the logout options displays only if the `id` is present, it makes the page go blank.

**functions.php**

```
function add_nav_menu_items( $items, $args ) {
//print_r(Auth::user()->id);
//if(Auth::user()->id){
    $items .= '<li id="myId" class="myClass"><a href="http://wordpress-ezmoneycpa-1.c9users.io/app/public/logout">Logout</a></li>';

//   }else{
// $items .= '<li id="myId" class="myClass"><a href="http://wordpress-ezmoneycpa-1.c9users.io/app/public/logout">Login</a></li>';
//}
return $items;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);
```

I just commented out the condition that I want to happen so it will work, but it only displays the logout menu. Once I remove that comment the page goes blank.

Comment: your code looks fine, have you php errors on? `No display. Just white` view source in your browser, you might spot something.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, you will likely find there is a fatal error happening. That fatal error will tell you where the problem is.